# When for %~t option return blank on batch file

Tags: batch-file

I was running the command `For %a in (hi.txt) do set filedate=%~ta` when I noticed that if the file does not exist, `%filedate%` does not get set. Are there other scenarios where that variable would not get set?

I checked:

- not exist file
- read only file
- hidden file